# multicolumn table in latex with non si units

Tags: tables, multicolumn, units, siunits

[image: Mean Roughness]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3hR4.jpg)

Hi.. Can someone help me with the code for this table along with packages for units like torr and sccm

```
\usepackage {multirow, multicolumn}
\usepackage {siunitx, mhchem}

\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{Mean Roughness}\label{tab:openrough}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lll@{}}\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Process parameters} & mean roughness (\si{\nm}) \\
 Pressure (\torr) & Nitrogen flow rate (sccm) & \\
\midrule
2 & 50 & 20 \\ 
2 & 50 & 27 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows us what you tried so far. Please also state where exactly the problem is: Is it the colors, the linebreaks in cells, the alignment...

Comment: In order to use non SI units with the `siunitx` package, you can use `\DeclareSIUnit\torr{torr}`.

Comment: I have problems with linebreaks and alignment. I m not concerned with the color. Also \torr works with mhchem package but i m not able to declare sccm. I get a fatal error and pdf cant be generated

Comment: Regarding the linebreaks and alignment, you might be interested in `\multirow` as well as `\multicolumn` and the `makecell` package.

Comment: Yes i use the '\multirow' and 'makecell' package already

Comment: Thanks for editing your question. How is `\torr` defined?  And why do you use `tabularx` if your table does not include an `X` type column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the usage of `\multirow` and `\makecell` commands, yo can achieve the following: (I have also defined two new units using the `siunitx` package and used `S` type columns for better alignment of numbers.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\DeclareSIUnit\sccm{sccm}
\DeclareSIUnit\torr{torr}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cS[table-format=3]S[table-format=2.2]@{${}\pm{}$}S[table-format=2.2]}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{{process parameters}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{3}{*}{\makecell[cc]{mean \\ roughness \\(in \si{\nm})}}}\\
\cmidrule(rl){1-2}
\makecell[cc]{pressure\\ (in \si{\torr})} & {\makecell[cc]{nitrogen gas flow \\(in \si{\sccm})}}\\
\midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{2} & 50  & 21.7 & 12.75\\
                   & 150 & 20.5 & 4.8\\ 
\midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{9} & 50  & 51.14 & 17.9 \\
                   & 150 & 24.8 & 12.7\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works well except that i get an error as !Undefined control sequence 
\DeclareSIUnit\sccm{sccm}

Comment: Do you load the `siunitx` package?

Comment: yes i have used `siunitx`

Comment: @SirReal You don't have to define units: just `\si{torr}` will work. However, I'm wondering what version you have: could you check your log for the line where `siunitx` is loaded?

Comment: @Joseph The Package is : siunitx 2017/11/26 v2.7k A comprehensive (SI) units package